# When two GCP VPN were created with same subnet IP, It causes troubleshooting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

I have created two GCP VPN tunnels for the same remote peer gateway IP. IKEv2 was used and routing type is policy-based. Also, I used the same Advertised IP ranges in both VPN tunnels. When I created one of them, it is up and running as the usual. However, if I created a second VPN tunnel, it causes troubleshooting. The status of the second VPN tunnel is "Negotiation failure". Also, first VPN tunnel doesn't reply back PKTS requests coming from the remote subnet. Can't we create two VPN tunnel with using same remote peer gateway IP and same advertised IP ranges?

[Routing and security part of VPN tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn7sd.png)

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that peer's configuration is not accepting the Cloud VPN request. Could you please let me know which on prem device that you are using, and in document [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers) you have the supported ciphers for Cloud VPN. Please take reference of this article to verify if your configuration on the peer side is correct.

As you mentioned that you have created 2 GCP VPN tunnels for the same remote peer gateway and one of which is working fine, it might also depend on the on prem device's capability of supporting multiple tunnels. Cloud VPN supports creating multiple tunnels that terminate on the same gateway IP address.Cloud VPN doesn't even know anything about interfaces on the peer side.  All it does is send packets to an IP address.

Also please let me know :

1. If you can see any traffic being sent to the on prem from GCP in the Stack driver logs for that VPN tunnel, and vice versa? If you see any errors, feel free to let me know.

You can tcpdump on your on prem side to see if any packets are being sent or if any attempt is bieng made to send them to GCP.

In document [2](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-peer-gateway) it shows, how to configure the peer gateway. Please take the reference of these articles to find out if you are using the right configuration on the peer end.
Also, please note that Cloud VPN does not support 1 to many NAT:[3](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/advanced#udp-encapsulation), so please make sure that it is not being used.